# PHP do every x time something else in a foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

As the title says: I have a foreach loop but every third time the loop will pass it must do something else. How to do this? Thanks in advance. I tried:

```
$count = 0
foreach ($cObjects as $oObject) {
   if ($count <= 2) {
     //do things
     $count = 0;
   } else {
     // do other things
   }
   $count++;
}
```

This didn't work ofcourse, while it resets the count everytime to 0.

Replacing `if($count <= 2)` to `if($count == 2)` works.

Comment: you have to show your code here

Comment: Yes, that's right, `zero` is less an `two`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer from Parixit works only on index array, for collection or associative array you will need a separate $count variable, something like this:

```
$count = 0
foreach ($cObjects as $oObject) {
   if ($count == 2) {
     //do things
     $count = 0;
   } else {
     // do other things
   }
   $count++;
}
```

Comment: Haha yes, it was quite simple actually but stared to long at my screen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know I understand it proper or not. But you should do something like this

```
foreach($all as $k=>$single) {
    if($k%3==0) {
        //do every third time
        continue;
    }

    //do something which will not execute every third time
}
```